# Is Magento playing with me? Products are not showing up on frontpage in the catalog, but at the New Articles they are showing up!

Tags: product, category, frontend

Is Magento playing with me? Products are not showing up on frontpage in the catalog, but at the New Articles they are showing up!

I had similar problems before in previous test databases, but that solved itself by a miracle, but this time i dont know what to do anymore.

I am not a programmer, i am just trying to make a new webpage without big costs.

Is there some code which i have to alter somewhere and how can i do it?
I dont have a direct access at the webserver, so programming the server is not an option, i can up- and download files with FileZilla for files which needs to be altered in de website itself.

I can approach the MySQL and the PHP options.

Please help me out, i tried everything i could manage to do with the websites option, product options and category options.

I am using Magento 1.9.3.1, PHP version 5.5.38, MySQL 5.5.52-cll-lve, Cpanel 60.0 (build 26), Apache 2.4.23.
(Demo-)Site: https://www.deduoffice.nl

Answer (score 1):

Clear the cache in the admin.

In this case it is most likely the Block cache, but it is also possible that it is the Layout cache.

Also, it is possible (more rare) that memcache or other caching systems could be affecting the results.

UPDATE:

Here is what I recommend... duplicate the exact code currently running on the home page so that its running on another (new) CMS page. If the collection results are the same as the home page, then its something in your code... if its different, then you know its something cache related.

Comment: I clear caches and I am indexing the pages after every change i make, it is just not working. I have only the standard mem cache program running from Magento itselfs.

Comment: Memcache is something different and runs on the server, and its possible that its configured by the hosting provider without you being aware that its running.

Comment: Duplication of the Home page in the CMS didnt help either, it stayed the same. Tomorrow I will ask my provider if they can reset the MemCache.
Hopefully that will help.

I even duplicated the product and saved, reindexed and recached it by every alteration to make it visibill, but that didn.t help either.

Comment: How are you attempting to display the product in the Home CMS page? Can you add the code to your question?

Comment: i guess you mean the catalog.xml, I am not a programmer?
I zipped my layout and template files which i am using, maybe there is an error in it. you can download it from here: [link](https://www.deduoffice.nl/deduoffice_layout+template.rar) `deduoffice`

Comment: I mean how are you trying to get the product(s) to appear on the page? This could include something like `{{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}} ` or by modifying the layout on the DESIGN tab of the CMS page editor in the admin.

Comment: this is the code i use in the homepage for the banner, sitemap and the new articles:

<p>{{widget type="nextend2smartslider3/slider" slider="1"}}</p>
<p></p><p></p>
<p>Product in the standard sitemap of Magento</p>
<p></p>
<p><a href="https://www.deduoffice.nl/catalog/seo_sitemap/product/">Product Sitemap</a></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<h2>New in our assortment</h2>
<p></p>
<h5 class="page-title">{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" products_count="3" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml" cache_lifetime="3600"}}</h5>
<p></p>
<h2>Onze lopende aanbiedingen</h2>